# Accessing a custom attribute from within an instanced object and mode validation

Tags: c#, .net

Working on a custom Attribute that inherit from Required Attribute

```cs
//My Custom attribute
public class RequiredParentAttribute: RequiredAttribute
{
    public RequiredParentAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResourceFW);
        ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(ResourceFW.RequiredParentError);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name, getParentName());
    }

    private string getParentName()
    {
        return "parentName;";
    }
}
```

I have a class Order that has two Addresses

```cs
public class Order
{
    ---
    public Address BillingAddress {get;set;}
    public Address ShippingAddress {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
    ---
    [RequiredParentAttribute]
    public string City {get;set;}
    [RequiredParentAttribute]
    public string ZipCode {get;set;}
}
```

my problem is that when I use the RequiredAttribute I get the following resut

```
City is required 
ZipCode is required
City is required 
ZipCode is required
```

```
City in Billing Addres is required 
ZipCode in Billing Addres is required
City in Shipping Address is required 
ZipCode Shipping Address  is required
```

the solution must stay generic because `Address` is used in multiple different entities.
To solve it, I tried to create a custom attribute but I couldn't retrieve the parent and from my understanding there's no way in .net to know who's the caller of this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that in standard .NET attribute usage, there is no built-in way to determine the parent or caller of an attribute applied to a property. Attributes are essentially metadata and don't have direct access to the context in which they are used.

However, if your goal is to create a custom attribute that enforces validation based on the parent object's properties, you can achieve this by using validation logic within your custom attribute itself. You can pass the parent object to the attribute or access it through a shared context, such as the ValidationContext.

Here's a modified version of your RequiredParentAttribute that attempts to enforce validation based on the parent object's properties:

```
public class RequiredParentAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return false;

        if (value is Address address)
        {
            // Here, you can access the parent object properties
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.City) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.ZipCode))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name);
    }
}
```

With this approach, you don't need to determine the caller of the attribute or access the parent explicitly. Instead, you check if the required properties (City and ZipCode) of the Address object are valid within the IsValid method of your custom attribute.

if you apply the RequiredParentAttribute to the properties within the Address class, it will check if both City and ZipCode are provided and not empty. If they are not, it will trigger the validation error message.

```
public class Address
{
    [RequiredParent(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [RequiredParent(ErrorMessage = "ZipCode is required")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

I assume you have control over how the validation process is invoked, such as using Validator.ValidateObject or similar methods. This approach doesn't automatically check the parent object's properties without explicit validation.